# Data uploads into the wrong node. What's wrong in the code?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to upload the current location of the driver to the busid("1" or "2") node which has the logged in driver's Uid. But, the problem is that it always uploads the location to node "1" even if the Uid is present under node "2". I need help in finding which node (either "1" or "2") has the Uid as the child.

```
int totalbusno = 2;
String driverbusid = "1";
mDatabaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
busReference = mDatabaseReference.child("Busno");
lat = location.getLatitude();
lon = location.getLongitude();
mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
assert mUser != null;
userid = mUser.getUid();



busReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= totalbusno; i++){
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(ds.child(String.valueOf(i)).hasChild(userid)){
                    driverbusid = String.valueOf(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

Submitdriverlocation submitdriverlocation = new Submitdriverlocation(lat, lon);
mDatabaseReference.child("Busno").child(driverbusid).child(userid).child("location").setValue(submitdriverlocation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(DriverMapsActivity.this, "Location Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(DriverMapsActivity.this, "Update Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

[image: Database Structure]

Answer (score 0):

You have constant value of driver id, check on top of your code its `String driverbusid = "1";`

That's why your data is always pushing on node with key 1.

```
// This will always refer to node with key 1
mDatabaseReference.child("Busno").child(driverbusid)
```

And update your `for` loop.

```
   for(int i = 1; i < totalbusno + 1; i++)
```

Your `for` loop should execute for next value which 2.

Comment: But, if i don't assign a value there, the app crashes. Even if i assign a value there , it's supposed to change inside the for loop right?

Comment: @AjayReal check my updated answer and if your will not initialise value then it would crash due to null key

Comment: Should i initialize the driverbusid to 1?

Comment: I would suggest you, put a check to avoid node update till you received valid Id. Otherwise it can cause issues

Comment: No.It did not. I still uploads to node 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151139/discussion-between-rahul-and-ajay-real).